# How to call await for function which returns string in network image & how to use if statements to decide different widgets based on output

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

Kind of a double question here:

First, I have created a function, which returns a string which is meant to be displayed as a network image... The problem is that, when I say

```
NetworkImage(await InformationFinder().getProfilePicture(_user)),
```

It asked me to convert it into async however, I have no clue where to add the async keyword.

Here is the code for the `getProfilePicture` method.

```
class InformationFinder {
  Future<String> getProfilePicture(FirebaseAuth _auth) async {
    var user = await _auth.currentUser();
    var profilePicture;
    Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
    return _firestore
        .collection('Users')
        .document('${user.uid}')
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      profilePicture = value.data['Profile Picture'];
      return profilePicture;
    });
  }
}
```

Second Question:

```
leading: widget.isFromGoogleLogin
                              ? CircleAvatar(
                                  child: Image(
                                    image: NetworkImage(
                                        await InformationFinder()
                                            .getProfilePicture(_user)),
                                  ),
                                  radius: 40,
                                )
                              : CircleAvatar(
                                  child: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
                                ),
```

How can I convert this into an if statement so that I have a few more possibilities because I have more than only 2 cases in which I want to display different widgets...

Comment: You add the async keyword the same way as you added in your first sample code, I would need more information for your best option though.
As for the second question, you can create a private method or a class that extends StatelessWidget depending on your needs for more advanced if-statements.

Answer (score 0):

1st Question:

I think you have to put the `async` after the `InformationFinder`, sou your code should be like:

```
class InformationFinder async {
  Future<String> getProfilePicture(FirebaseAuth _auth) {
    var user = await _auth.currentUser();
    var profilePicture;
....
```

2nd Question:
You can convert that like this using an immediate anonymous function:

```
leading: (() {
  if(/* First condition */){
  // Your code
  } else{
  //Your code
  }
}())
```